# Finding out importable modules in Python

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython

iPython has this excellent feature of being able to auto-complete modules and this works extremely well in there.

For the longest time, I've had a shell function that allows me to change directories to where a given module is located. It does this by trying to import the name of the module from the first argument and looking into its `__file__`.

What I would like to do is to find out the importable modules that are available so I can write an auto-complete function for this little helper.

I know that for a give module, I can do something like `dir(module_name)` and that would give me what I need for that module but I am not sure what to do to find out what I can import, just like iPython when you do something like:

```
import [TAB]
```

Or

```
import St[TAB]
```

Which would autocomplete all the importable modules that start with `St`.

I know how to write the auto-completion functionality, I am interesting in just finding the way of knowing what can I import.

**EDIT:**

Digging through the IPython code I managed to find the exact piece that does the work of getting all of the current modules for the given environment:

```
from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion

for module in module_completion('import '): 
    print module
```

The reason I'm printing the results is because I am actually using this for ZSH completion so I will need to deal with the output.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you could iterate through the paths in `sys.path` looking for python modules, as that is exactly what `import` does. Other than that, Python won’t have an index or something for all modules, as the imports are resolved on run-time, when it’s requested. You could easily provide an index for the built-in modules though and maybe have a cache or something for previously imported modules.